# How to quote a question or answer as spoiler?

Tags: support

I have seen people post with blank spaces with a header spoiler when the mouse is hovered on top of it the text comes up. How do I do that. I'm sure is this the right medium to ask about this, if it no i'm sorry but please do guide me on how to make the disappear thing on spoilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Paragraph

Since you can't use double new line in spoiler block to separate paragraphs, you need to work around by adding line breaks by ending the lines in 2 spaces.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
>
>  Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Source:

```
>! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.  
>!  
>! Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

To be more explicit (space between `>!` and `TEXT` is optional):

```
>! TEXT<SP><SP><NL>
>!<SP><SP><NL>
>! TEXT
```

## Heading. List. Numbering. Blockquote. Horizontal Line.

There is currently no support for Markdown quote, Markdown heading, Markdown list and Markdown numbering inside spoiler block. You need to use HTML to emulate them.

> ### Unordered list
>
> - Item 1
> - Item 2
>
> ---
>
> ### Ordered list
>
> 1. Item 1
> 2. Item 2
>
> > Here is a famous quote.

Source:

```
>! <h2>Unordered list</h2>
>!
>! <ul><li>Item 1</li>
>! <li>Item 2</li></ul>
>! <hr>
>! <h2>Ordered list</h2>
>! <ol><li>Item 1</li>
>! <li>Item 2</li></ol>
>!
>! <blockquote>Here is a famous quote.</blockquote>
```

## Spoiler banner

I personally prefer to use a blockquote as a spoiler banner when the spoiler content is too many, and the content needs to be formatted to make it presentable. I place the banner before the spoiler content, and leave the spoiler content outside spoiler block.

> ### `/!\` Spoiler Warning
>
> The content from this point on contains spoilers. Read it at your own risk.

Source:

```
> ## `/!\` Spoiler Warning

> The content from this point on contains spoilers. Read it at your own risk.
```

(There are better ways to present the warning sign, but this is the simplest way and readily typable).

Answer (score 3):

The markup is:

`>! Spoiler paragraph.`

How it actually looks:

> Spoiler paragraph.

Comment: should there be space after >!
or it doesn't matter.

Comment: You could test it yourself in the http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/857/introducing-the-formatting-sandbox-in-the-middle-of-nowhere